# When using "using" do we have any situation to include catch block where we dispose the object and do nothing else

Tags: c#, exception, using

I came across this section of code somewhere during my learning path. I find one observation here that, even though the author is using "using" block and create the "ts" object, he uses try catch block inside the using block where in catch section, he disposes the object "ts" explicitly calling Dispose method. I feel it is unnecessary. I am not understanding why he needs try and catch here if he has to "only dispose the object".

My questions:

1. Do we really need try catch here ? On what occasion, it will serve purpose in this example ?
2. Is disposing this way correct when using "using" block ? How does it react as in GC process ? Its an overhead right ?

Appreciate if both questions can be explained in a way that a beginner can understand.

```
using (TransactionScope ts = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.RequiresNew))
{
    try
    {
        ServiceReference1.Service1Client obj = new ServiceReference1.Service1Client();
        obj.UpdateData();
        ServiceReference2.Service1Client obj1 = new ServiceReference2.Service1Client();
        obj1.UpdateData();
        ts.Complete();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        ts.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

This certainly does seem unnecessary to me.  The `using` statement will compile to a `finally` block wrapping the whole code block, which will be executed regardless of whether or not an exception is thrown.

Essentially, he's writing this:

```
TransactionScope ts;
try
{
    ts = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.RequiresNew);
    try
    {
        ServiceReference1.Service1Client obj = new ServiceReference1.Service1Client();
        obj.UpdateData();
        ServiceReference2.Service1Client obj1 = new ServiceReference2.Service1Client();
        obj1.UpdateData();
        ts.Complete();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        ts.Dispose();
    }
}
finally
{
    ts.Dispose();
}
```

Which is a bit silly.  It's *especially* silly that he's completely ignoring (or, "swallowing") the exception.  99.99999993% of the time, that's a bad idea.

Comment: Thank you David. I have a doubt in your code above. If you are using Dispose in finally, why you want to use Dispose in catch as finally is always touched irrespective of anything. I am a beginner, could you please explain.

Comment: @Divine: That's the point, the code here is redundantly redundant.  A `using` block is nothing more than a `try`/`finally` block with a call to `Dispose` on the supplied object.  There's no need for the call to `Dispose` in the `catch` block.  I would further argue that there's no need for the `catch` block (and, thus, the inner `try`) at all since this is poor exception handling.

Comment: @Divine - This isn't David's code. This is the same code you submitted, but with the using block *explained*.

Comment: @David: Sorry I got confused, again had a look at the code and understood, my sincere apologize. I never observed the "two try blocks". Thank you for explaining David :)

Answer (score 1):

In this particular code snippet, the only thing the catch clause does is that it prevents the exception from bubbling up. In effect, it ignores the exception.

The dispose method here is used to rollback the transaction, but since dispose will be called anyway once code is outside the using block it remains unnecessary.

Comment: @Divine - Rolling back means canceling out anything that the transaction has done so far. This is used when you either want the whole of the transaction to succeed, or the whole of it to fail, instead or partially succeeding or partially failing.

Comment: I think in the case of a `TransactionScope` a rollback is implied upon disposal if it's not already been completed.  Indeed, there is no `Rollback` method: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.transactions.transactionscope.aspx

Comment: @David - I think you're right! It never crossed my mind that there's no rollback method. How odd!

Comment: TransactionScope rolls back on any Exception by design.

Comment: @David: Could you please explain "upon disposal" thing in detail. Are you saying that, if the ts object is disposed after exiting using block, the rollback is performed ? Sorry I really dont understand the first statement, I am new :( please explain.

Comment: @Divine: When a `TransactionScope` object is disposed, it implicitly rolls back any still-open transaction that it contains.  So if the call to `.Complete()` was never reached because of an error then the transaction will be rolled back.

Comment: @David: Thank you so much, I understood it now :) Really appreciate it, thanks for your time explaining me :) Cheers

Answer (score 1):

1. No, you do not need the catch here.
2. By "This way", I assume you're not referring to the double dispose implemented by the try/catch block here. And yes, this is the proper way (lose the try/catch part).

When code leaves the `using` block, the object in question, `ts` here, will be disposed of. The only way your program can leave this block without the object being disposed is if you're:

1. Killing the program
2. Terminating the thread

So you do not need the try/catch part to correctly dispose the object.

What that try/catch code *does*, however, is to swallow any exceptions in the code in the try block. The dispose call, however, is unnnecessary.

Comment: Actually, killing the process/AppDomain releases all resources, managed or non-managed. So disposal is carried out.

Comment: Well, there _are_ ways to prevent a `finally` block from executing: http://publicvoidlife.blogspot.com/2010/07/try-and-catch-me.html

Comment: Thank you Lasse for the detailed explanation :)

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand there is no reason for the `Dispose` call. There is however reason for the `try` `catch`. For example if an `UpdateData` call fails you may want to make some adjustments and then retry. You may also want to handle different exceptions differently, without a catch block you won't have any opportunity to do that.

Answer (score 1):

ts.Dispose is called on a finally section implicitly when using "using" anyway.
If however you do not catch the exception , it will be thrown , where as in your example,
the exception is silently swallowed by the catch block.

Answer (score 1):

[using Statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx)

> The using statement ensures that Dispose is called even if an
>   exception occurs while you are calling methods on the object. You can
>   achieve the same result by putting the object inside a try block and
>   then calling Dispose in a finally block; in fact, this is how the
>   using statement is translated by the compiler.

So yes, that dispose in the exception block in your posted code is uneccessary.

Answer (score 1):

Any object defined via `using` must implement `IDisposable`. That object is `Disposed()` as soon as it goes out of scope (meaning control leaving the `using` block), by whatever means — a `return` statement, a `goto`, an Exception, etc. So catching exceptions in order to ensure that the `using` variables are properly disposed is redundant.

This code:

```
using ( MyDisposableObject x = new MyDisposableObject() )
using ( AnotherDisposableObject y = new AnotherDisposableObject() )
{
  x.Foo() ;
  y.Bar( x ) ;
}
```

is **exactly identical** to this code:

```
MyDisposableObject x = new MyDisposableObject() ;
AnotherDisposableObject y = new AnotherDisposableObject() ;
try
{
  x.Foo() ;
  y.Bar( x ) ;
}
finally
{
  x.Dispose() ;
  y.Dispose() ;
}
```

There are however, reasons, you might want to catch exceptions within the `using` block. Among them:

- Actually *handling* the caught exception.
- Logging and rethrowing the caught exception.
- Intentionally swallowing a specific exception, for instance, to allow execution to continue. Reasons you might want to do that include, for instance, [demanding permissions](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/315529) in order to see if you are allowed to do something. If the demand fails, a SecurityException is thrown. Catching that allows you to take action, for instance, notifying a user that they lack permission to open the file they asked for.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer is no. TransactionScope implements IDiposable so the C# using statement will automatically call Dispose() after executing the code block.

The usefulness of try/catch blocks in this context is to possibly complete the transaction for some types of exceptions.

In most cases it's enough to just call ts.Complete(); as the last statement in the using block. This ensures that any exceptions thrown before cause the transaction to be rolled back.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to call Dispose inside the using statement. It deals with that for you.

There is nothing wrong with using a try catch inside the using if there is some exception you want to handle there, just dont do the dispose.

Answer (score 0):

Nope, that particular `try..catch` is completely useless (well, functionally at any rate, it *does* silently eat any exceptions you might encounter).

Note that this isn't an equivalence, the `using` clause is stronger because it calls `Dispose` even on success, since it expands to a `try..finally` instead of just a `try..catch`.

Answer (score 0):

1) You only need try/catch if you're going to really treat the exception or log and throw it again. Any other use for try/catch is a bad practice. In this case, all you're doing is to dispose `ts`, so you'll not need it as you are inside an `using` block.

2) No, you  don't need to call dispose: using block will take care of it even if there's an exception.